# Chrometophone example

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have been going through the ChromeToPhone example. There are intents

com.google.ctp.UPDATE_UI

com.google.ctp.AUTH_PERMISSION

Are they built in android intents or custom for the application. If custom, where are the activities that respond to them in the Chrometophone example.

Answer (score 0):

Those are custom intents defined by the Chrome to Phone app, as is hinted by the package name in the action strings: `com.google.ctp`.

[SetupActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/android/apps/chrometophone/SetupActivity.java#70) programmatically registers a listener for this broadcast action. There isn't a receiver registered in the manifest for this because it's only ever relevant to the particular activity.